# How to set a buffer local variable (e.g. fill-column) for one specific .org file?

Tags: org-mode, file-local-variables, fill-column

I use `fill-column 80` for the majority of my files. Howover, I have a `.org` with a table that is slightly wider than 80 columns. I'd like to automatically set `(setq fill-column 100)` for that file only, without manually call it everytime I open the said file. Is it possible?